# Microservices Communication Design

Tags: python, api, microservices

I would like to know how to create a communication for each services. I am using API Gateway for the outside of the system to communicate with the services within. Is it necessary for a service to call another service through API Gateway or just directly into the service itself ?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can design your communications strategies in many ways. Obviously  you can use your API Gateway to do this (I assume that you are using this [pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)) but this isn't a good idea because to begin it is not  a good use of the pattern and for other hand many people think that the use of apirests should never be used to inter-communication of mservices. One a best approach to make this instead is base the communications  on asynchronous message-passing, to do this you can use [Publish–subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern), but always you can take a look to [Event Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) very used too.

This is a simple list of some articles that maybe could help you, take a look:

- [Building Microservices: Inter-Process Communication in a Microservices Architecture](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-inter-process-communication)
- [Why RESTful communication between microservices can be perfectly fine](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/why-restful-communication-between-microservices-can-be-perfectly-fine/)
- [Pattern: Messaging](http://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html)
- [Technical Approach of Inter-Service Communication](http://howtocookmicroservices.com/communication/)

Is a lot of info if you don't have previous experience in this issues but with a bit of researching you will find soon a good strategy to use in you project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. There a lot of ways to do it, I am still looking and learning from your links. This mservices cost a lot of time to return a response if the data are separated on many services. I am still learning how can I make it more efficient communication between client and my microservices, also between my services within my microservices.

Comment: Yeah, it's the first thing that every people think, the performance. Because of this we need think carefully how and through of that what we send our data between our services. Maybe you need to search fastest tools to develop your services, what language are you using? Where are you thinking to deploy this? Maybe the performance problems that you have could be solved with another question.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. I am developing my services using Python. Right now, Azure is used by our team to deploy our services. Designing microservices is one of the hardest part hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Api gateway is not needed for Internal service to service communication
But, you need a service registry or some kind of dynamic  load balancing mechanism to reach the services

Comment: You usually don't need a load balancing mechanism to do this, it necessary another kind of tools.